# Loading a dll from its resources

Tags: c#, dll, resources

So, my program has a DLL in its resources, which i am trying to read this way:

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(Resources.func);
        Type type = assembly.GetType("Func");
        dynamic functions = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        functions.Test();
```

For some reason it keeps throwing a null error at this line:

```
dynamic functions = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

The namespace of the DLL is Func, and the name of the class is Func too. Can anyone help me with this? I have been googling for the last hour but i just can't find the solution to it.

UPDATE

When i make the class non-static, and use assembly.GetType("Func.Func");, it throws a RuntimeBinder exception when i do functions.Test();. Maybe that helps a little more?

Comment: `assembly.GetType("Func.Func")`, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the complete type name of the `Func` class. If the namespace is `Func` and the type is `Func`, you should try using:

```
Type type = assembly.GetType("Func.Func");
```

Comment: That makes it throw a System.MissingMethodException
It can't make an abstract class

Comment: Finally, this did the trick, now i can call the functions using functies.GetMethod("Test").Invoke(null, null);

Comment: Glad you've made it. I don't know how is your `Func` class defined, but you cannot instantiate, or call methods of abstract classes, unless they are static. It seems calling a static method is your particular case, so `.Invoke(null, ...)` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GetType("Func.Func")`, it will return a class named Func in a namespace called Func, as far as assembly is successfully loaded.